# Autocomplete text box like "Tags" text box on Stack Overflow

Tags: c#, jquery

How can I design & implement a "Tags" text box like the one seen on Stack Overflow?

Answer (score 3):

That looks like [jQuery autocomplete](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Autocomplete) to me, with `multiple` set to `true` and `multipleSeparator` set to space (`' '`).